# move .android folder on windows 10 android studio

Tags: android-studio, emulator

since last update of android studio, I can't run the emulator, and get this massage: 
17:37   Emulator: C:\apps\androidSdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=C:\Users\׳‘׳ ׳™׳”.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_28_x86.avd\cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576: Could not open 'C:\Users\׳‘׳ ׳™׳”.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_28_x86.avd\cache.img.qcow2': The system cannot find the path specified.

any idea why?
its possible that the problem is with the android emulator path, which contains my user name in hebrew. is there a way to move this path to somewere else? all solutions with environment variables didn't work on windows 10.

Comment: Same as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/.

Comment: it's not, since this question and it's answers are old and doesn't work on windows 10